# Как добавить картинку на фон?

Tags: android, java

Как добавить картинку вместо фона, если она весит 400кб и разрешение 2048x1536? Кусок вытащить нелезья, так как картинка выгляджит как будто взяли пару банок краски и опрокинули на нее. ) Просто такую картинку если загрузить, это очень сильно повлияет на производительность, верно? Как же быть тогда?

Comment: Вот это смотрели? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: 1. Определить требуемый размер картинки (под экран?).    
2. Пересайзить картинку под этот размер (так, как по ссылке @Andreich).

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, в фотошопе ее лучше уменьшить? Я так и делаю. Легко, быстро и качественно.

Comment: Ну я же просто делаю под Андроид под все экраны...А там их штук 30 будет....